# Let $f: X \to X$ be such that $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$. To show that $f$ is onto.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $f: X \to X$ be such that $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$. To show that $f$ is onto.

Since the function $f$ satisfies $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$ we can say that the function is uniformly continuous.

Now let us assume that $f$ is not onto then $f(X) \subset X$, a proper subset. Then how can I bring a contraction to show that $f$ will be onto??

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No, it's a completely different topic: at least because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact.

Comment: @egreg Look at Qiaochu Yuan's answer there. That post has been the de facto default duplicate target for this question (look at how many dupes ppint to it).

Answer (score 8):

Let $x_0\in X$ and define
$$g:X\to\mathbb{R},\quad g(x)=d(f(x),x_0).$$
It is easy to show that $g$ is uniformly continuous. Since $X$ is compact, $g$ attains a minimum at some $y_0\in X$, i.e.
$$d(f(y_0),x_0)\leq d(f(x),x_0),\quad\forall x\in X.$$
We will show that this $y_0$ does it, i.e. $f(y_0)=x_0$. Suppose, for contradiction, that $f(y_0)\neq x_0$ and let
$$\epsilon_0:=d(f(y_0),x_0)>0$$
Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ inductively by
$$x_1=f(x_0),\quad x_{n+1}=f(x_n).$$
Then, for any $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>n$, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_m,x_n)&=d(f(x_{m-1}),f(x_{n-1}))=d(x_{m-1},x_{n-1})=\cdots=d(x_{m-n},x_0) \\
&=d(f(x_{m-n-1}),x_0)\geq d(f(y_0),x_0)=\epsilon_0
\end{align*}
Thus, $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ cannot have any Cauchy subsequence. This contradicts that $X$ is compact, since a compact metric space is sequentially compact. So $f(y_0)=x_0$, and hence $f$ is onto.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $f(X)\subset X$ is compact. Suppose we have $x\not\in f(X)$. Then by compactness we have $d(x,f(X))=\epsilon>0$.

Now define $x_n=f^{n}(x)$, i.e. apply $f$ $n$-times.

Note that $(x_n)_n\subset f(X)$, so $(x_n)_n$ must have a convergent subsequence (sequential compactness of $f(X)$).

We have $d(x,x_n)\ge \epsilon$ by definition of $\epsilon$. But by invariance of the metric under $f$ we also have

$$d(x,x_n)=d(f(x),f(x_n))=d(x_1,x_{n+1})=\cdots=d(x_{m},x_{n+m})$$

for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$. So $d(x_{m},x_{n+m})\ge \epsilon$ for all $n,m$, which implies that $(x_n)_n$ cannot have a convergent subsequence, contradiction!

Comment: For completeness of this answer, when two sets $F$ and $K$, $F$ is closed and $K$ is compact, the distance between these two sets $> 0$